# how to save image path to sql database in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, prepared-statement

I have to save the image path chosen by jfilechooser to sql database and load that image every time from that sql path. Im using preparedStatment . But I got the path saved in sql database without "\" . Here is part my code.. Please help me on this.

```
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
conn = DBConnection.ConnectDB();

 try {
            JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();
            choose.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f = choose.getSelectedFile();
            if (f != null) {
                fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();

                String sql = "UPDATE addskin SET Path='" + fileName + "' WHERE Name='Assigned'";
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.execute();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I replaced ... but I got sql error.                             fileName = f.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\", "-");                   ERROR -java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard solution is [Escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Quick solution is replace slash with some special character, while change it back later.

Comment: I replaced ... but I got sql error.                             fileName = f.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\", "-");                   ERROR -java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1

Comment: Maybe "-" is a bad choice for your DB? Also I could name my file as image-1.png. How about fileName = fileName.replace("\\","\\\\")

Comment: thnks Mingtao  .... It works... thnk u so much... replaceAll dosnt works.. but replace() working well.. thnks a lot..